# Looking for help to clarify the structure of a sentence

Tags: grammar

I'm preparing for the GRE test and there's a sentence that really puzzles me.

> Marion Palfi's photographs would have received greater recognition from historians had her work been done in an era when most aspects of photography were static rather than in a state of transition.

Can anyone help me to make clear which word or component does **had her work been done** modify? And, because the sentence already has a verb **receive**, I'm not sure if **had** in the same phrase is a verb or a past participle.

Comment: In this case, "had her work..." = "if her work..." does that help?

Comment: See also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28967/would-you-tell-me-in-which-condition-we-can-invert-a-conditional-sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'*had something been done*' kind of a structure is used to say ***'if'*** it had been done. In other words, using 'had' in such context introduces the imaginary condition.

For instance, I'm not an expert in fixing a flat tire. But, I fixed it somehow. Since it's not fixed properly, you can say...

> *Had it been done by some professional, it'd ....*

Check an example mentioned in [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/had)

> *Had I known (= if I had known), I would have come home sooner.*